# Is it possible to query against the ldap server stored in drupal without reconnecting?

Tags: authentication-authorization

I have a drupal install that uses LDAP to authenticate users.  I use that same LDAP to return user info such as roles, employee photo, email, role, and the center they work at.

```
    $ds=ldap_connect("ldap-example.com");  
            if ($ds) { 
                $r=ldap_bind($ds);     
                $sr=ldap_search($ds, "DC=tpcontact,DC=co,DC=uk",$search);  
                $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr)or die('get info fail');
}
```

I need to make it so that the server is pulled from drupal.  So, if it is possible to query ldap without reconnecting, I need to do that.  Otherwise I need to query the drupal DB's ldap_servers table, the only problem is that I dont have access to a MySql database that has LDAP enabled to see what the field is.

Comment: can you reword this question to be more clear. Your question doesn't make much sense. Any time you want to query mysql or ldap you have to connect first. A connection only last the duration of a single url page request from a site visitor.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the name of the field that contains the address...

Comment: ok, i see you know the `ldap_query`, `ldap_feeds` and `ldap_views` are all designed to let you run queries like this at any time. you shouldn't have to write the query yourself (but more power to you if you can).

Comment: If you need confidential info removed from a question, you need to flag the question for mod attention. Editing it will not make the info go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I assume that you are using the [LDAP module](https://drupal.org/project/ldap)?

I've not looked into the code they use however I would expect that they will close the connection before your module runs, and even if they don't the connection won't be a global variable so your module will not have access to it.

If you are writing a custom module then you *do* have access to the DB - just use db_query and fetch the results, or look in your settings file for your connection details. Then you can connect directly to your DB using software like [Navicat](http://premiumsoft-navicat-lite.software.informer.com/).

The table ldap_servers has a field called **address**. This is where you will find the address to your ldap server.